# Trying to send sms text message from php but never reaches

Tags: php, sms

Trying to send sms text message from php to Verizon phone number.

Message is sent successfully (echo "sent") but it does not show in the phone.

```
$to      = '281818888@vtext.com';
subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = "From: mymail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: mymail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: mymail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: mymail@gmail.com\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: mymail@gmail.com\r\n";

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    echo "sent";
else 
    echo "notsent";
```

This method also sends emails but they drop into spam. Both issues might be related.

Any idea or opinion?

Comment: sms? This is emails

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale — To an SMS forwarding address

Comment: I don`t think this is duplicate exactly since this question is trying to send a text message NOT an email. Although, the same method (mail) is used, the goal is different, so can the underlying problem.